# pgfplots fill between, error: missing number trated as zerro

Tags: pgfplots

I try to test all examples from pgfplots manual, which shows use "filling between". For this purpose I construct simple MWE like the following one:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}    
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

     \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:1,samples=2] {x};
\addplot+[name path=B] table {
x y
0 2
0.5 -1
1 3
};
\addplot fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Compiling of this and any other example in manual as well from examples here on SE fails with the same error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero
<to be read again>
     \advance
```

If I force compilation, I receive expected results. I can not figured out whats going wrong with this my test. Do I miss something in settings of my MWE?

Without `fill between` I can compile these examples without this error. I have recent 64-bit MikTeX with recent version of pgfplots.

Comment: Hm, this compiles fine for me (TL 2015 on Linux, daily updated)

Comment: It complies fine for me too (TeXLive 2015 on Mac).

Comment: I suspect, that the problem should be somewhere in my` pgf/tikZ` and `pgfplots` installation. So (in desperation) I uninstalled both, refresh FNDB base, reset PC and reinstall `pgf` and `pgfplots` again. Now works all! Thanks all for comments! I will close the question as solved by re-installations of packages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by re-installations of pgf and pgdplots packages.